# Guacamole logout function does not logout of web broswer

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, guacamole

I am having issue with Guacamole server where I cannot logout of the web session once I am logged in. We use Keycloak for identity management and Guacamole server for RDP sessions. The versions on both application is fairly latest but had this issue for long time since the inception. Search google but unable to find any fix however there are people who already experienced similar issue. Apart from logout issue everything functions without any issue. Couple of errors I can see on the browser is shown below:

RROR on browser:

```
{
  "message":"Session not associated with authentication provider \"openid\".",
  "translatableMessage":{
    "key":"APP.TEXT_UNTRANSLATED",
    "variables":{
      "MESSAGE":"Session not associated with authentication provider \"openid\"."
    }
  },
  "statusCode":null,
  "expected":null,
  "type":"NOT_FOUND"
}
```

Comment: I tried Guacamole some time ago but did not use it much, so can't help.
Currently we use Igiko, it acts generally the same as guac: RDP Gateway and Web access, and has the tunnel feature - to bypass NATs.
They should have WebAPI so probably you can integrate it if required.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have found what is the reason for not working Guacamole logout - it is Keycloak SSO. It uses cookies for keeping users logged in.
What you need to do:
Go to the realm -> Authentication -> Flows -> Choose the flow you use from the drop-down list, usualy it is "brwoser" or clone of it -> Authentication type "Cookies" set to Disabled.
If you need to keep SSO - limit time in the Realm settings.
Try now.